# Retrieve the array data from the document in the Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is my firebase setup. [image]

The problem I faced now is how should I retrieve the array data inside the document, **item_detail** using the streambuilder and listview and display a output like this

[image]

I have go through many website about the streambuilder but I cant find the solution I want
Is it possible to do this?

Appreciate very much for the favor.

**Error**

[image: error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `StreamBuilder` to get the data by passing this code to the `stream` parameter of the `StreamBuilder`:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('lists').doc(documentId).snapshots()
```

It returns a `Stream` of `DocumentSnapshot` from which you can get the data by calling `.data()`.

This returns a `Map<String, dynamic>` object from which you can get the items from the array by getting the field `item_detail`.

This returns a list that can be used in the `ListView` widget.

Check out the code below which does the above and implements the UI in your question.

```dart
    StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('lists')
                .doc(documentId)
                .snapshots(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
    
              final DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data;
    
              final Map<String, dynamic> documentData = document.data();

              if (documentData['item_detail'] == null) {
                return Text('No item now');           
              }

              final List<Map<String, dynamic>> itemDetailList =
                  (documentData['item_detail'] as List)
                      .map((itemDetail) => itemDetail as Map<String, dynamic>)
                      .toList();
    
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: itemDetailList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final Map<String, dynamic> itemDetail = itemDetailList[index];
                  final String name = itemDetail['name'];
                  final String quantity = itemDetail['quantity'];
                  final String price = itemDetail['price'];
                  final DateTime date = (itemDetail['date'] as Timestamp).toDate();
    
                  return Card(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                            child: Text(
                              '${date.day}/${date.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 4.0,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                name.toUpperCase(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 4.0,
                              ),
                              Text('Quantity: $quantity'),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 4.0,
                              ),
                              Text('Total price: $price'),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 4.0,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red,),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
```

Comment: but it return this error if the data is null initially. Where should I put the condition to make it return a Text("No Item now"). 
I update the error at the question